# How to enable Horizontal paging for each Section in UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, swift4

I was using an app the other day which appeared to separate its `UITableView` sections (events for each day of the month) into separate `PageViews`. Here is a gif of the functionality: https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohBV4yNhpYOFoURxe. 
When I tried using a page view to accomplish this it seemed that you could only use separate `ViewControllers` for each page, rather than different sections.
Any idea on how one would go about doing this? I’m at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using a collectionView as reusable tableView cell, which means, sections and cells from your tableView can be a collectionView. And then you set your collectionView cells as big as the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to do this in one UI element, use UICollectionView. 
UITableView appearing and interactions are very limited.
this could be a good starting point:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/156794/custom-uicollectionviewlayout-tutorial-parallax